# Order of tasks (handlers) putting to taskqueue via post and dispatch

Tags: c++11, boost-asio

The output is:

```
Handler A
Handler B
Handler D
Handler E
Handler C
```

Given,

- post() puts the handler into the taskqueue and returns immediately
- dispatch() can run the task immediately if the main thread already calls run() (which is the case)

then,

- why "Handler E" wasn't run before B and D ? It was dispatch(), and main thread already runs the io_context after all.
- why "Handler C" was run last ? It kinds of make sense as it was post within post. But still the order of the tasks being put to the taskqueue isn't very self-explained.

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    io_service.dispatch( [](){ cout << "Handler A\n"; } );

    io_service.post(
        [&io_service]() {
            cout << "Handler B\n";
            io_service.post(
                [](){
                    cout << "Handler C\n";
                }
            );
        }
    );

    io_service.post( []() {
            cout << "Handler D\n";
        }
    );

    io_service.dispatch( [](){ cout << "Handler E\n"; } );

    cout << "Running io_service\n";
    io_service.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything works fine here.

In your current code you call `io_service.run()` as the last statement. So all calls of `post`/`dispatch` are equivalent and mean put a handler into the queue and returns immediately.

Completion handlers are called within `run` method.

`dispatch` can call handler without queuing only if `run` works while `dispatch` is being called, what is not your case.

What happens in details:

```
dispatch(A)    // queue:  A
post(B)        // queue:  A,B
post(D)        // queue:  A,B,D
dispatch(E)    // queue:  A,B,D,E
run() was invoked, now completion handlers can be called 
pop A
pop B -> in here, C is pushed, so queue is: D,E,C
pop D
pop E
pop C
```

If you want to let `dispatch` invoke handlers without queuing, you have to start `run` in background thread before putting any tasks:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::io_service::work work{io_service};

std::thread th([&](){ io_service.run(); });  // run started

io_service.dispatch( [](){ cout << "Handler A\n"; } );
// ...
th.join(); // we are waiting here forever
```

And now you can replace `post` to `dispatch` inside `B` handler. After `B` was pushed into the queue, `C` is called (`dispatch` is used while `run` is working), and as last `D` and `E` are invoked.

Comment: Thanks, you explained the taskqueue very well. Would be good if you can dwell in a bit more:

1) It looks like the io_service::work isn't really necessary here (it just keeps the io_service busy right?)

2) As you launch a new thread to run the io_service. "Handler E" is now expected to run immediately without being queued, ie it should run before B,D - but actual run still shows that E is after B,D. Any reason why?

Comment: [1] Yes, `io_service::run` hangs, you need to delete `work` instance to let `run` end (`work` can be created onto heap by smart pointer, then reset it). [2] No, you need to remember that when `post` is called, it pushes handler into queue, but `run` is already running, so why wouldn't `run` take/pop `B`,`D` tasks and perform them, before `E` is dispatched ? - here is some race between popping from queue (`B`,`D`) and invoking `E`.